# Safari error. Javascript ajax json object - could not fetch properties. object may no longer exist

Tags: php, json, ajax, object, safari

I have an Ajax call to a PHP backend. It is working fine in chrome but when I ran it in safari I am getting a '**could not fetch properties, object may no longer exist**' error against this line in the code -

dataType: "JSON",

Here is the function. Probably something really simple. I actually found this code online and repurposed it. Not really a developer just fudging my way through :)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! As I say, no errors in Chrome.

Thanks
Dave

```
            function insertProjectData() {

            var projectuid=$("#projectuid").val();
            var projectIdentifier=$("#projectIdentifier").val();
            var projectPIRDate=$("#projectPIRDate").val();
            var projectName=$("#projectName").val();
            var projectManagerName=$("#projectManagerName").val();
            var projectSponsorDept=$("#projectSponsorDept").val();
            var projectSponsorName=$("#projectSponsorName").val();
            var projectSponsorContact=$("#projectSponsorContact").val();
            var projectGTMDate=$("#projectGTMDate").val();
            var projectTargetBudget=$("#projectTargetBudget").val();
            var projectActualCost=$("#projectActualCost").val();
            var projectScope=$("#projectScope").val();
            var projectScopeDelivered=$("#projectScopeDelivered").val();

            if ($('#projectDeliveredTimeline').is(':checked')) {
                var projectDeliveredTimeline = "Yes";
            }
            else {
                var projectDeliveredTimeline = "No";
            }
            if ($('#projectDeliveredPlan').is(':checked')) {
                var projectDeliveredPlan = "Yes";
            }
            else {
                var projectDeliveredPlan = "No";
            }
            var projectComments=$("#projectComments").val();

            // AJAX code to send data to php file.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",   q
                url: "insert-projectdata.php",
                data: {projectuid:projectuid,projectIdentifier:projectIdentifier,projectPIRDate:projectPIRDate,projectName:projectName,projectManagerName:projectManagerName,projectSponsorDept:projectSponsorDept,projectSponsorName:projectSponsorName,projectSponsorContact:projectSponsorContact,projectGTMDate:projectGTMDate,projectTargetBudget:projectTargetBudget,projectActualCost:projectActualCost,projectScope:projectScope,projectScopeDelivered:projectScopeDelivered,projectDeliveredTimeline:projectDeliveredTimeline,projectDeliveredPlan:projectDeliveredPlan,projectComments:projectComments},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    closeitem(projectarea);
                    $("#ProjectSaved").show();
                    setTimeout(function() { $("#ProjectSaved").hide(); }, 2500,);
                    $('form[name=projectForm]').get(0).reset();
                    window.location.replace("lessons.php");
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

            });
        }
```

Strangely this (another page) is working fine!?...

```
function insertAreaData() {
            var areauid=$("#areauid").val();
            var areaName=$("#areaName").val();
            var areaDesc=$("#areaDesc").val();

            // AJAX code to send data to php file.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert-areadata.php",
                data: {areauid:areauid,areaName:areaName,areaDesc:areaDesc},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    closeitem(areaarea);
                    $("#AreaSaved").show();
                    $('form[name=AreaForm]').get(0).reset();
                    setTimeout(function() { $("#AreaSaved").hide(); }, 2000,);
                    window.location.replace("lessons.php");
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

            });

        }
```

Edit: I have now tested in internet explorer also and having the same issue.

Comment: Is the stray `q` a typo? And the extra `,` in the setTimeout? And is this the *exact* error message you receive? "could not fetch properties, object may no longer exist"? Is it that exactly or are you rewording it?

Comment: Hi @JoeFrambach, yes the `q` is a typo, sorry about that! as for the `,` in Timeout that is on purpose but that doesn't mean it is correct :) And yes the wording in Safari console is - Object Could not fetch properties. Object may no longer exist. error projects.php:69 line 69 being the `datatype: "JSON",` line.

Comment: Could the issue be in the php backend page that it is posting to?

Comment: On a whim, could you comment out the line `closeitem(projectarea);` and see if the error persists? This variable isn't in the scope you provided, and Safari does complain sometimes in async situations when an object it knows about has been pulled from under it. The usual solution is to wrap your success callback in an iife with `projectarea` passed as an argument. I'll write that up in a full answer if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: Or, replace your entire success callback with a `function() { console.log('this works!'); }`, just to whittle down the possible issues to try to triangulate the root problem.

Comment: Commenting out the closeitem didn't help sadly. I'll try replacing the callback. Should it look like this? `success:
               function() { console.log('this works!'); }`
           },`

Comment: Yup, if the error goes away, then we know the problem is in the success callback. If the error is still there, then you'll have to keep digging.

Comment: Sadly no 'this works' message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out that the form was posting an page was reloading and for some reason Google Chrome was handling this for me, while Safari and IE were not.

I added the following onsubmit comment to the form:

`<form id="Project" name="projectForm" onsubmit="return false;">`

and it prevented it from executing when I was clicking the submit button and instead ran the javascript.

Just for completeness here is the submit:

`<input type="submit" class="submit" id="projectSubmit" onclick="insertProjectData()" value="Save Project">`

So as expected a simple thing in the end...